# Rstudio crashes on erroneous DBI::dbExecute operation. Error handling doesn't work

Tags: r, sqlite, rstudio, dbi

If I pass an erroneous statement through `DBI::dbExecute` or `RSQLite::dbExecute` on a SQLite database on disk, instead of throwing that error, RStudio crashes saying:

```
The previous R session was abnormally terminated due to an unexpected crash. You may have lost 
workspace data as a result of this crash.
```

Here is my `sessionInfo()` before running the breaking command:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)  
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)   
Running under: Oracle Linux Server 7.8   
Matrix products: default   
BLAS: /sys_apps_01/R/R-3.6.0/lib/libRblas.so   
LAPACK: /sys_apps_01/R/R-3.6.0/lib/libRlapack.so   
locale:  
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C    
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NAME=C    
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C LC_TELEPHONE=C    
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C    
attached base packages:   
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base    
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):   
[1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6 compiler_3.6.0 pillar_1.4.3 later_0.8.0    
[5] R.methodsS3_1.7.1 R.utils_2.8.0 tools_3.6.0 packrat_0.5.0    
[9] bit_1.1-14 testthat_2.3.2 digest_0.6.19 pkgload_1.0.2    
[13] RSQLite_2.1.1 memoise_1.1.0 lifecycle_0.2.0 tibble_3.0.3    
[17] R.cache_0.13.0 pkgconfig_2.0.2 rlang_0.4.7 DBI_1.0.0    
[21] cli_2.0.2 rstudioapi_0.11 R.rsp_0.43.1 withr_2.1.2    
[25] desc_1.2.0 generics_0.0.2 vctrs_0.3.4 bit64_0.9-7    
[29] tidyselect_1.1.0 rprojroot_1.3-2 glue_1.4.1 R6_2.4.0    
[33] fansi_0.4.0 blob_1.1.1 purrr_0.3.3 magrittr_1.5    
[37] backports_1.1.4 promises_1.0.1 htmltools_0.3.6 ellipsis_0.3.0   
[41] assertthat_0.2.1 mime_0.6 xtable_1.8-4 httpuv_1.5.1   
[45] crayon_1.3.4 R.oo_1.22.0
```

and below is a reprex:

```
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(
drv = RSQLite::SQLite(),
dbname = "test_DB.sqlite3"
)

create_time_chk_query = "CREATE TABLE time_chk (
year INTEGER,
month INTEGER,
quarter INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT pk_timechk PRIMARY KEY (year, month)
)"

DBI::dbExecute(conn, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS time_chk")
# Creating the table first time
tryCatch({
DBI::dbExecute(conn, create_time_chk_query)
}, error = function(err){
print(err)
})

# Breaking command - Creating table again without dropping it
# Expected behavior - Catch and print error
# Observed behavior - Session crash and restart
tryCatch({
DBI::dbExecute(conn, create_time_chk_query)
}, error = function(err){
print(err)
})
```

Comment: Would you be able to update R and try again?

Comment: Cannot do that. It’s on company’s Rstudio server, so any update to package or R version is not a feasible option

Comment: For a data point: I cannot reproduce this on win10, R-4.0.4, DBI-1.1.1, RSQLite-2.2.1, working in emacs/ess (not RStudio, though I do not expect that to be an issue).

Comment: Even if you cannot control what is *currently* installed in the base library, though, you may be able to create a temporary directory and install newer versions of packages into that temp-directory. While I don't suggest that this is the only/best long-term fix, it will help you determine if the problem is due to a package version alone (and, if so, convince your administrators to update).

Comment: That sounds interesting. I will try that. Thanks